# Is there a hot key to run the contents of the Firebug Console?

Tags: javascript, firefox, console, firebug, hotkeys

If you're using Firebug (Firefox) and you type in javascript in the Console command line and press enter it executes. However, for good reason, when you expand the command line into a multi-line text area to the right then pressing enter does not execute the code. Instead you have to click Run at the lower left of this window.

Is there a hot-key/shortcut to run the contents of the command window? (i.e. without mouse clicking.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Command + Enter does it for me. (on OS X)

For windows it's likely Ctrl + Enter.

Comment: Sometimes this works but for some reason it will often just show the last result again. Any idea why?